# Script para enviar email

Tags: php, email

Estou criando uma página, onde tem a parte de contato, já fiz o formulário, etc., mas na hora de enviar, não consigo uma função que faça enviar para meu email.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

```
<article id="contact">
    <h2 class="major">Contato</h2>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <div class="field half first">
            <label for="name">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="message">Mensagem</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar mensagem" class="special" /></li>
            <li><input type="reset" value="Apagar tudo" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <ul class="icons">

        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-whatsapp"><span class="label">Whatsapp</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

[image: Tela de contato]

Comment: Qual a linguagem, jovem?

Comment: Você não vai conseguir fazer isso somente com HTML e Javascript. Precisa utilizar um linguagem server side tipo ASP, PHP, C#, JSP,...

Comment: Teria alguma solução com PHP? Eu estou estudando PHP ainda, vamos dizer que ainda não estou apto a desenvolver isso, mesmo sendo simples. Mas pra esse meu código acima, qual função em PHP resolveria? Obrigado!

Comment: Procure utilizar o PHPMailer, vai faciliar o seu trabalho e é facil de configurar, https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Poderiam me dar exemplo em PHP com esse meu código? Pôs está meio complicado com o tópico que o rapaz passou. No meu servidor, por exemplo, vou ter que criar alguma pasta?

Comment: Veja esse link http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) para executar essa tarefa.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form">
    <div class="field half first">
        <label for="name">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field half">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="message">Mensagem</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar mensagem" class="special" /></li>
        <li><input type="reset" value="Apagar tudo" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
       event.preventDefault();

       $.ajax({
          type : 'post',
          url : 'seu_arquivo_php.php',
          data: $("#form").serialize(),
          success: function( response ) {
               console.log( response );
          }
      });           
});
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php

      require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];

       $mail = new PHPMailer;

       $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Habilita SMTP
       $mail->Host = 'seusmtp.com.br';  // Especifique o SMTP que você contratou
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Habilita autenticação SMTP
       $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // Usuário do SMTP
       $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // Senha do SMTP
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // criptografia (tls ou ssl)
       $mail->Port = 587;                                    // Porta de conexão SMTP

       $mail->addAddress($email, $name);     // Para quem?

       $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information'); //Resposta pra qm?
       //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com'); //Cópia do email
      // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com'); //Cópia Oculta


       $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Formata o E-mail em html

       $mail->Subject = 'Teste de envio'; //Assunto
       $mail->Body    =  $message ;//Mensagem
       $mail->AltBody =  $message; // texto simples para clientes de correio não-HTML

       if(!$mail->send()) {
           echo 'Não foi possível enviar.'.'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       } else {
            echo 'Enviado com sucesso!';
       }
 ?>
```

Comment: Recomendo evitar de responder perguntas que poderiam ser duplicatas, veja as [**dicas de como encontrar a resposta ideial**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5719/como-incentivar-quem-vai-responder-a-fazer-uma-pesquisa-prévia-no-site#5721)

Answer (score 2):

Acho que seria algo mais ou menos assim:

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();

$nome = $_POST["/*Nome aqui*/"];
$email = $_POST["/*Email aqui*/"];
$mensagem = $_POST["/*Mensagem aqui*/"];
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: /*Seu nome aqui*/" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Responder à /*Seu email aqui*/" . "\r\n\r\n";

$mailBody = "/*Aqui você pode estrurar um corpo em HTML caso queira uma mensagem mais bonita, sem esquecer o CSS também*/";

if(mail("{$nome} <{$email}>, /*Seu nome aqui*/ </*Seu email aqui*/>", "/*Seu nome aqui*/", $mailBody, $headers)){
    $_SESSION["success"] = "Email enviado com sucesso";
    header("location:index.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION["error"];
    header("location:index.php");
};
```

*Ressaltando que este é apenas um formulário exemplo, no caso, pode estar visualizando um similar no próprio `php.net`

*Seu servidor deve permitir o envio de formulários, caso seja `localhost`, pode não funcionar, para testar recomendo um plano gratuito na hostinger ou outros hostsites

*Use este script como o `action=""` de seu `form` e `method="post"`

link: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Recomendo evitar de responder perguntas que poderiam ser duplicatas, veja as [**dicas de como encontrar a resposta ideial**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5719/como-incentivar-quem-vai-responder-a-fazer-uma-pesquisa-prévia-no-site#5721)

Comment: As vezes o problema dele pode ser outro, sendo assim, a resposta da duplicata pode não resolver o problema

Comment: Não estou aqui para brincadeirinhas, estou aqui lhe dando uma dica para o **bom funcionamento** do site, então por favor leve como uma dica construtiva. Fico grato ;)

Comment: Eu n sou idiota, vlw flw

Answer (score -5):

Apenas com linguagens front-end você consegue só através de ferramentas como o [formspree](https://formspree.io/) que foi o que eu fiz com um [site](http://dev.jonathanmmachado.surge.sh/) meu, como usei o [surge](https://surge.sh/) para hospedar, e ele só aceita linguagem front-end, tive que fazer isto.

Você até consegue fazer com o javascript, mas informações pessoais (como senhas e api key por exemplo) vão ficar a expostas.

Exemplo de como ficaria com o formspree:

```
<form method="post" action="https://formspree.io/seu@email.com">
        <div class="field half first">
            <label for="name">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="message">Mensagem</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar mensagem" class="special" /></li>
            <li><input type="reset" value="Apagar tudo" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: Acabei de ver aqui, e o servidor que vamos usar não da suporte a PHP, Só posso usar JavaScript, que no caso é óbvio pôs é client side. Existe algum modo (Qualquer modo) de eu conseguir fazer isso? Obrigado!

Comment: Como expliquei ali, existe ferramentas (como o formspree) que envia o e-mail pra você com as informações preenchidas no formulários (a tag <form>)  a única coisa que você deve fazer é adicionar o atributo action, redirecionando para o link https://formspree.io/seu@email.com e pronto, o site faz o back-end pra você e envia um e-mail em forma de tabela com o nome dos inputs e os valores. Se você ver no código que eu coloquei, já fiz a alteração a única coisa que você precisa fazer é mudar o seu@email.com para o e-mail que você quer.